# How to stop ArangoDB?

Tags: linux-mint

I'm using ArangoDB and I was wondering how to stop it. I tried:

```
$ sudo arangodb stop
2018/01/31 17:10:55 Failed to shutdown starter: Post
http://127.0.0.1:8528/shutdown: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8528: getsockopt: connection
refused
```

I also tried:

```
$ /etc/init.d/arangod stop
bash: /etc/init.d/arangod: No such file or directory
```

I am using Linux Mint 18.1.

**Update**

I think the command maybe:

```
/etc/init.d/arangodb3 stop
```

Comment: Will `sudo systemctl stop arangodb` work on Linux Mint?

Comment: Your command did not show an error. Is there a way to confirm that ArangoDB has now stopped?

Comment: Look at the currently running processes with `ps aux` or try accessing the database. I'm not too familiar with `systemctl` but you should also be able to do `sudo systemctl is-active arangodb` (or with `status` in place of `is-active`).

Comment: "/etc/init.d/arangodb3 stop" seems to work!

Comment: There you go then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The ArangoDB documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/GettingStarted/Installing/Linux.html) says

```
/etc/init.d/arangod stop
```

And it goes on to say

> The exact commands depend on your Linux distribution. You may require root privileges to execute these commands.

From comments it is clear that the version of ArangoDB that you are using provides a script with a slightly different name than the above, so

```
/etc/init.d/arangodb3 stop
```

is the way to go for you.

Comment: "$ /etc/init.d/arangod stop
bash: /etc/init.d/arangod: No such file or directory". I'm on Linux Mint.

Comment: @tyebillion You have not told us what distribution of Linux you are using and the documentation clearly says that it may depend on that.

Comment: Sorry, I just added it to my comment.

Comment: @tyebillion I updated my answer to include the fact that you found the right script name.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to stop the arangodb service:

```
sudo systemctl stop arangodb
```